# AFNetworking+UIImage Downloading Low-Resolution Image First

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, afnetworking

I am having some troubles using the +UIImage `setImageWithURL:` method. What I would like to do is first send an asynchronous request for a thumbnail image. This image is very small so it should load fairly quickly. I also want to send another asynchrous request to download the hi-res version of the image since it takes a little longer to load.

I assumed it would be something like:

```
NSURL *thumbURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.server.com/uploads/thumbs/%@.png", name]];
[imageView setImageWithURL:thumbURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PHImage.png"]];

NSURL *hiRezURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.server.com/uploads/%@.png", name]];
[imageView setImageWithURL:hiRezURL];
```

but that just loads the hi-res image and takes too long. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the implementation of `UIImageView+AFNetworking.m` you see that it declares a property:

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, retain, setter = af_setImageRequestOperation:) AFImageRequestOperation *af_imageRequestOperation;
```

and the first thing that `- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage` method does (it actually first calls `-setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:`), is `[self cancelImageRequestOperation];` and that actually cancels the operation of the class property, `af_imageRequestOperation`.

That means, when you call the method again (on your 3rd) line, it cancels the operation of the 1st line.

A better approach would be if you use `+ imageRequestOperationWithRequest:imageProcessingBlock:success:failure:` and set the image of image view in the success block. I think if you use this method, you need also to call `[operation start];` afterwards.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out doing something very similar. I used the method `setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:` and called `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` when it was complete and used the image returned as the placeholder.