# AFNetworking setImageWithURL:placeholderImage where placeholder is also from a url

Tags: ios7, uiimageview, afnetworking

**UPDATE**

While trying to find a solution I've happen to notice the following two questions:

- [AFNetworking+UIImage Downloading Low-Resolution Image First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618523/afnetworkinguiimage-downloading-low-resolution-image-first?rq=1)
- [UIImageView+AFNetworking setImageWithURL with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730138/uiimageviewafnetworking-setimagewithurl-with-animation?rq=1)

I'll investigate using these two post and will update if it came to be helpful.

**ORIGINAL POST**

I got this horizontal feed that contain 1 item per page. Each item contain some textual info and a background image that I'm pulling from a url.

Since the background images are in high quality it might take some time to download it, so I figured out I'll need a placeholder. The placeholder I would like to use is an extreme blurred, really low quality version of the background image which means I need a variation of the beloved `AFNetworking` method: `[bg setImageWithURL: placeholderImage:]` - something that will know how to accept a placeholder that comes from a url (making the assumption that the placeholder image weigh MUCH less then the original size one).

To sum up, my question is: **How to get an image from a url and use a placeholder, where the placeholder image is from a url as well?**

**Things I tried:**

- Creating another `UIImageView *placeholder` and use the `[placeholder setImageWithURL:]` method on it with the url of the placeholder, then using the `placeholder.image` as the placeholder of the `[bg setImageWithURL: placeholderImage:]` call.
- Using the `[placeHolderImage setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:]` method, and in the success block calling the `[bg setImageWithURL:]` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was on the right track and due to lack of attention it didn't work. (had problem with retain cycle)
Using the two links I provided in the question, I eventually managed to solve the problem by using the `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:` for the placeholder, and on the success block, make another use of the `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:` method - this time for the original image.

I'll provide a code snippet of my solution - might help someone in the future:

```
    //Protect against retain cycle
    __weak UIImageView *weakBg = bg;

    //get the placeholder - note the placeholderImage parameter is nil (I don't need a placeholder to the placeholder
    [bg setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:placeholderURL]]
              placeholderImage: nil
                       success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                           UIImageView *strongBg = weakBg; // Make local strong reference to protect against race conditions
                           if (!strongBg) return;

                           //Protect against retain cycle
                           __weak UIImageView *weakBg = strongBg;

                         //Get the original bg with the low quality bg as placeholder
                           [strongBg setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:originalBgImageURL]]
                                           placeholderImage:image
                                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                               UIImageView *strongBg = weakBg; // Make local strong reference to protect against race conditions
                               if (!strongBg) return;

                               //Do stuff

                           } failure:NULL];
                       } failure:NULL];
```